ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gnuradio.lora_sdr'
Trying to follow the install from https://github.com/tapparelj/gr-lora_sdr I have done the following as in the install instructions:
git clone https://github.com/tapparelj/gr-lora_sdr.git
cd gr-lora_sdr/
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-py39_4.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
source ~/.bashrc
conda env create -f environment.yml 
conda activate gr310
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
(sudo) make install -j4
sudo ldconfig

make test - this didnt do anything and outputs No tests were found!!!
gnuradio-companion & - this works and I see Lora blocks in GNU radio
python3 examples/tx_rx_functionality_check.py - results in import gnuradio.lora_sdr as lora_sdr ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gnuradio.lora_sdr'
python3 examples/tx_rx_functionality_check.py is to verify the installation but I get import gnuradio.lora_sdr as lora_sdr ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gnuradio.lora_sdr' as an error. This command should run a GNU Radio python file but it is missing a module and I do not know where I went wrong in installing it. I have tried reinstalling and I have tried checking my path, I currently have this at the end of my .bashrc:
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gnuradio:/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gnuradio:$PYTHONPATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

I have tried to look for an reinstall the repo above and verify my path is set correctly, is there some other package that I need that I am overlooking maybe?

cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local

here, you explicitly installed it somewhere that neither your conda environment's python, nor your runtime .so loader, looks, because
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gnuradio:/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gnuradio:$PYTHONPATH

probably gets overriden when you activate the conda env.
So, use cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFX=/path/to/your/conda/env .. and install without using sudo. The sudo ldconfig, in general, is rarely needed on any modern Linux system, by the way, lest you're really updating the location of LD directories or their contents, not when installing something.

Is there a reason that you switched the order of .. in cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFX=/path/to/your/conda/env .., Also how can I check where my path to conda is, I have never used it before this project.

No reason for switching – the order doesn't matter. Check conda info --envs to see the prefixes of all envs you set up.

while in the target conda environment (and therefore $CONDA_PREFIX being defined): cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$CONDA_PREFIX"
